# SQLAlchemy unable to add data to table

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I created a SQLite database with the below code, but when I try to input data into the database, nothing appears. I'm not sure what is going wrong..

**Code to create database and tables**

```
# Create a database engine
engine = create_engine(r'sqlite:///Data\test.db', echo=True)
Base = declarative_base()

class Framework_Market(Base):  # Parent table for Child table

    __tablename__ = 'Market'  # Defining the Parent table name
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    # Tables that it will create
    Country = Column(String(255))

    def __init__(self, market):
        self.market = market

class Framework_Equity(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'Equity'  # Defining Child Table
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    # Tables that it will create
    Date = Column(Date)


    stock_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('Market.id'))
    stock = relationship("Framework_Market", backref=backref("Equity", order_by=id))

    def __init__(self, date):  

        self.date = date

# Create Tables
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

**Code to add values to tables**

```
engine = create_engine(r'sqlite:///Data\test.db', echo=True)

# Create a Session
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

# Create a market
new_market = Framework_Equity("United States")
new_market.Equity = [Framework_Equity(datetime.date(2001, 1, 18))]  

# Add the record to session object - Putting it into the database
session.add(new_market)
session.commit()
```

As of now, whenever I run the code to input data into the tables, and I try using "DB Browser for SQLite" to see if it has been recorded into the database, it shows that there is an empty field created in the database. It doesn't record "United States" in the table, nor does it record the "date" in the joining table.

What am I doing wrong here???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your column is named `Country = Column(String(255))` in `Framework_Market`, but in your `__init__()` method you set value to `self.market = market`. The same with the second model: `Date = Column(Date)` vs. `self.date = date`. Change your code to following and it will work:

```
class Framework_Market(Base):
    # ...

    def __init__(self, country):
        self.Country = country

class Framework_Equity(Base):
    # ...

    def __init__(self, date):  
        self.Date = date
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It works! But for the 2nd portion where you asked me to change `new_market.Equity` to `new_market.stock`, it didn't work. The original one that I had worked though.

Comment: Oh, you're right that was incorrect. Removed it from answer.